# Show window contents while dragging is not working in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

While dragging the horizontal or vertical bar, the contents do not move on Microsoft Excel. But the window contents move while doing the same process on a browser or any other software. I have not frozen any panes, tried split pane also but of no use. It may be a simple solution, but I am not able to figure out how. I have huge excel sheets and have to regularly drag the sheet up, down, left & right to look for the data that I need. Pressing page up and down is not a convenient method.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you go to the Developer tab in the Ribbon bar, then click on Properties, is there a `ScrollArea` defined?

Comment: Can also happen if titles are blocked while the most bottom-right cell was selecting, effectively blocking all cells from moving.

Comment: @spikey_richie `ScrollArea` is empty.

@LPChip that is not the case

Comment: If you press the arrow keys, do they scroll or move the cell around? And if you press Scroll-lock, what happens then? Normally if scroll-lock is turned on, arrow keys scroll the window instead when pressing arrow keys.

Comment: @LPChip When I press the arrow keys, the cell moves around. And when the scroll lock is on, the cell doesn't move but the window does move when the arrow keys are pressed.

Comment: Does this issue occur with blank workbook? If yes, it's recommended to run Excel in safe mode to troubleshoot startup items and COM add-ins. Besides, go to File > Options > Advanced > Untick the box of "Zoom on roll with IntelliMouse", and check the Mouse driver. If not, please try to right-click sheet name > Move or Copy, check the box of "Create a copy", then check this issue.

Comment: @Emily Yes, it happens with blank workbook as well. I tried everything what you have suggested, unfortunately none worked.